# How to pass the amount of decimals as an argument in an R plot.regsubsets?

Tags: r, plot, visualization

In R, the y axis of `plot.regsubsets` is always rounded off to two digits. I would like to define how many digits to use myself.

Judging from the source of the function the two decimal rounding is hard-coded ([line 33](https://github.com/cran/leaps/blob/263fee141f2eb5b5ee9abaaaf75b1cf9c446b2ae/R/plot.subsets.R#L33)).

What is the easiest way to adjust the amount of digits of the y axis for these plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One could redefine the whole function every time R is started, perhaps extend the function with an extra argument `digits`:

```
plot.regsubsets<-function(x,labels=obj$xnames,main=NULL,
                          scale=c("bic","Cp","adjr2","r2"),
                          col=gray(seq(0,0.9,length=10)),digits=2,...){
    obj<-x
    lsum<-summary(obj)
    par(mar=c(7,5,6,3)+0.1)
    nmodels<-length(lsum$rsq)
    np<-obj$np
    propscale<-FALSE
    sscale<-pmatch(scale[1],c("bic","Cp","adjr2","r2"),nomatch=0)
    if (sscale==0)
        stop(paste("Unrecognised scale=",scale))
    if (propscale)
        stop(paste("Proportional scaling only for probabilities"))

    yscale<-switch(sscale,lsum$bic,lsum$cp,lsum$adjr2,lsum$rsq)
    up<-switch(sscale,-1,-1,1,1)

    index<-order(yscale*up)

    colorscale<- switch(sscale,
                        yscale,yscale,
                        -log(pmax(yscale,0.0001)),-log(pmax(yscale,0.0001)))

    image(z=t(ifelse(lsum$which[index,],
          colorscale[index],NA+max(colorscale)*1.5)),
          xaxt="n",yaxt="n",x=(1:np),y=1:nmodels,xlab="",ylab=scale[1],col=col)

    laspar<-par("las")
    on.exit(par(las=laspar))
    par(las=2)
    axis(1,at=1:np,labels=labels)
    axis(2,at=1:nmodels,labels=signif(yscale[index],digits))

    if (!is.null(main))
        title(main=main)
    box()
    invisible(NULL)
}
```